# How to convert " ' " to " ` " in java

Tags: java, mysql

The syntax that from the java code is not applicable to mysql. The `setString()` from java will come out with ' and not ` which is not accepted in mysql.

I tried in my localhost to run the code, it really not accepting 'doctor' and only accept ``doctor`.

Below are my code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM ? WHERE id = ?");
ps.setString(1, "doctor");
ps.setInt(2, 123);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

and there is an error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''doctor' WHERE id = 123' at line 1
```

Comment: You can't bind the tablename in your query.

Comment: is there any other alternate way to solve that??

Comment: `PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM doctor WHERE id = ?");` which is pretty silly; since you're providing the `id`.

Comment: If you really need to be able to specify the tablename, then you can do something like: `String sql = String.format("SELECT id from %s where id = ?", tblName); PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your code produces following query:

```
SELECT id FROM 'doctor' WHERE id = 123
```

As you can see table name is used as a String which is invalid SQL Syntax, so you can either hard code `table name` and or if you really want it to be dynamic you can achieve it like:

```
String sql = String.format("SELECT id from %s where id = ?", tblName); 
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, 123);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```